# Xcode : How to use cmd + x to either cut a line or cut the selected text

Tags: xcode, macos, ide, xcode10, macos-mojave

Pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> without selecting text in other IDEs, cuts the complete line. Same goes for <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> which copies, instead of cutting. Otherwise, if some text is selected, only that region is cut.

How do I do this in Xcode?

I added the following in the `IDETextKeyBindingSet.plist` to add cutting line and copying line functionality:

```
<key>My Custom Commands</key>
<dict>
    <key>Cut Current Line</key>
    <string>selectLine:, cut:</string>
    <key>Copy Current Line</key>
    <string>selectLine:, copy:</string>
</dict>
</dict>
```

But obviously binding these to <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> (or <kbd>c</kbd>) doesn't allow cutting/copying selected region. I understand I can set it to some other keybinding. But, as a force of habit, <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> (or <kbd>c</kbd>) suits better.

Is there any way to do this? Maybe an extension?